# Submit docker which contains fat jar to Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, docker, apache-spark-sql, dcos

I want to submit a docker container which contains 'fat jar' to a Spark cluster running on DC/OS. Here's what I have done.

1. `mvn clean install`, so the jar resides here /target/application.jar
2. `docker build -t <repo/image> . && docker push <repo/image>`
3. Now my DC/OS is able to pull the image from my private repository

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM docker-release.com/spark:0.1.1-2.1.0-2.8.0  # I extended from this image to get all necessary components

ADD target/application.jar /application.jar # just put fat jar under root dir of Docker image

COPY bootstrap.sh /etc/bootstrap.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/bootstrap.sh"]
```

Here's what bootstrap.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.spark.sample.MainClass --master spark://<host>:<port> --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 20G --total-executor-cores 100 /application.jar
```

I deployed this image as a service to DC/OS, where Spark cluster also runs, and the service successfully submit to Spark cluster. However, Spark cluster is not able to locate the jar because it sits in the service docker.

> I0621 06:06:25.985144  8760 fetcher.cpp:167] Copying resource with
> command:cp '/application.jar'
> '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e8a89a81-1da6-46a2-8caa-40a37a3f7016-S4/frameworks/e8a89a81-1da6-46a2-8caa-40a37a3f7016-0003/executors/driver-20170621060625-18190/runs/c8e710a6-14e3-4da5-902d-e554a0941d27/application.jar'
>
> cp: cannot stat '/application.jar': No such file or directory
>
> Failed  to fetch '/application.jar':
>
> Failed to copy with command 'cp '/application.jar'
> '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e8a89a81-1da6-46a2-8caa-40a37a3f7016-S4/frameworks/e8a89a81-1da6-46a2-8caa-40a37a3f7016-0003/executors/driver-20170621060625-18190/runs/c8e710a6-14e3-4da5-902d-e554a0941d27/application.jar'',
>
> exit status: 256 Failed to synchronize with agent (it's probably
> exited)

My question is:

Does the jar need to be placed somewhere other than inside the Docker container? It doesn't make any sense to me, but if not, how can Spark correctly find the jar file?

Comment: It may be of no use to you since you are using maven, but in sbt you can use a native packager & DockerPlugin to build docker images however you want from sbt:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager
https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker

And just run: `sbt docker:publishLocal`

I would venture that maven will have something similar